# Qt - does a QTimer::timeout() signal result in a QEvent?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

[Qt doc:](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#per-thread-event-loop)

> If no event loop is running, events won't be delivered to the object.
>   For example, if you create a QTimer object in a thread but never call
>   exec(), the QTimer will never emit its timeout() signal. Calling
>   deleteLater() won't work either. (These restrictions apply to the main
>   thread as well.)

Does this mean that signal `void QTimer::timeout()` will also issue a [`QEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#Type-enum)?
If so, where does the Qt doc state this?

Comment: See: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimerevent.html

Comment: `QTimer` and `QTimerEvent` are two different ways of using timers in Qt. See the [Qt doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#alternatives-to-qtimer) for more information. `QTimer` uses signal/slot communication while `QTimerEvent` (created by `QObject::startTimer` and handled by `QObject::timerEvent()` or and event filter) are, well, events. But both require an event loop in the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

> where does the Qt doc state this?

Nowhere, because it shouldn't matter to the user of `QTimer`. The timer event is an implementation detail. It is delivered to the timer object itself, so you'd really have to go out of your way to intercept it. Here's how `QTimer` works:

```
class QTimer : public QObject {
  Q_TIMER
  QBasicTimer m_timer;
protected:
  void timerEvent(QTimerEvent * ev) override {
    if (ev->timerId() == m_timer.timerId())
      emit timeout();
  }
  /*...*/
};
```

If you think about it, there's no way of emitting any signals without running the code that emits the signals, and the only way to safely run such code that emits things asynchronously is to code for run-to-completion chunks that cede control to the event loop at every opportunity. The event loop is notified by the platform that a timer has timed out, and emits a signal right then. You'd be in deep trouble if Qt issued signals such as timer timeouts from intrusive asynchronous callbacks like Unix signals: just read about how few things you can do while in a signal handler - it'd be no different than an interrupt handler.